# Jquery and Javascript scroll image on click from outside divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a lightbox that I built where you can on a div with an image and then the image opens larger with a lightbox effect in a new div.  I want to have arrows where you can click to scroll forward and back through the images in the other outside divs.  I am new to JQuery and javascript and I have tried every way I can think of and I am just missing something on how to get this to work.  I have attached the basics of my code as reference.

The high and show code is not working either because it is not detecting the other divs for some reason.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("img").click(function(){
  $src=$(this).attr("src");
  $title=$(this).attr("title");
  $alt=$(this).attr("alt");


if(!$("#lightbox").length>0){
   $('body').append("<div id='lightbox'><span class='closer'>X</span><span class='nextimg'>></span><span class='previmg'><</span><div class='lightbox_container'><img src='' title='' alt=''><p>" + $title + "</p></div></div>");
   

   $("#lightbox").show();
   
   
   
   
   //*********************************************************
   if(!$(this).parent("#lightboxsm img").next().length>0){
    $(".nextimg").show();
   } else {
    $(".nextimg").hide();
   };
   
   $("body").on('click','.nextimg',function(){
    $newsrc=$("#lightbox img").attr("src");
    $newtitle=$("#lightbox img").attr("title");
    $newalt=$("#lightbox img").attr("alt");
    
    
    $("#lightboxsm img").next("lightbox img").attr('src', $newsrc);
    
   });
   
   //*********************************************************
  
  }else{
   $("#lightbox img").attr("src",$src);
   $("#lightbox img").attr("alt",$alt);
   $("#lightbox img").attr("title",$title);
   $("#lightbox").show();
  }
 });
 
 
 //Closes the lightbox***************************************
 $("body").on('click', '#lightbox .closer',function(){
  $("#lightbox").hide();
 })
    
    });
```

```css
.lightboxsm {
 width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden;
 /*float:left;*/
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px;
 position:relative;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.lightboxsm img{
 width:auto;
    height: 175px;
 object-fit: cover;
}

#lightbox{
 position:fixed;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 z-index:200;
}

#lightbox img{
 max-width:80%;
 max-height:80%;
 position:fixed;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 margin:auto;
}

.closer {
 display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
 float:right;
 margin:5% 10%;
 z-index:250;
}

.closer:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}

.nextimg {
 display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
 float:right;
 margin:5% 10%;
 z-index:600;
 clear:right;
}

.nextimg:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}

.previmg {
 display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
 float:left;
 margin:5% 10%;
 z-index:600;
 clear:left;
}

.previmg:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lightbox_container">
            <div class="lightboxsm" id="img1">
                <img src="http://2017.sunkissed-villas.com/images/1.png" alt="1"/>
            </div>
        
            <div class="lightboxsm" id="img2">
                <img src="http://2017.sunkissed-villas.com/images/2.png" alt="2"/>
            </div>
            
            <div class="lightboxsm" id="img3">
                <img src="http://2017.sunkissed-villas.com/images/3.png"/>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the nextimg selector was not accessing the parent before it was getting the next() so there was no next element. Let me know if the updated snippet works. I also made it so that it hid the next/prev button if there were no next or previous images.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected')
    $src=$(this).attr("src");
    $title=$(this).attr("title");
    $alt=$(this).attr("alt");


    if(!$("#lightbox").length > 0){
      $('body').append("<div id='lightbox'><span class='closer'>X</span><span class='nextimg'>></span><span class='previmg'><</span><div class='lightbox_container'><img src='' title='' alt=''><p>" + $title + "</p></div></div>");
       
      $("body").on('click','.nextimg',function(){
        $newimg=$('.selected').parent().next().find('img')
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected')
        $newimg.addClass('selected')
     $("#lightbox img").attr("src", $newimg.attr("src"));
        checkPrevNext();
      });
      
      $("body").on('click','.previmg',function(){
        $newimg=$('.selected').parent().prev().find('img')
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected')
        $newimg.addClass('selected')
     $("#lightbox img").attr("src", $newimg.attr("src"));
        checkPrevNext();
      });
    }
      $("#lightbox").show();
      $("#lightbox img").attr("src",$src);
      $("#lightbox img").attr("alt",$alt);
      $("#lightbox img").attr("title",$title);
      checkPrevNext();
   });
     
  $("body").on('click', '#lightbox .closer',function(){
    $("#lightbox").hide();
  })
  
  function checkPrevNext() {
    if($('.selected').parent().next().find('img').length > 0) {
      $(".nextimg").show();
    } else {
      $(".nextimg").hide();
    };
    
    if($('.selected').parent().prev().find('img').length > 0) {
      $(".previmg").show();
    } else {
      $(".previmg").hide();
    };
  }
});
```

```css
.lightboxsm {
 width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden;
 /*float:left;*/
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px;
 position:relative;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.lightboxsm img{
 width:auto;
    height: 175px;
 object-fit: cover;
}

#lightbox{
 position:fixed;
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 z-index:200;
}

#lightbox img{
 max-width:80%;
 max-height:80%;
 position:fixed;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 margin:auto;
}

.closer {
 display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
 float:right;
 margin:5% 10%;
 z-index:250;
}

.closer:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}

.nextimg {
 display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
 float:right;
 margin:5% 10%;
 z-index:600;
 clear:right;
}

.nextimg:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}

.previmg {
 display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
 float:left;
 margin:5% 10%;
 z-index:600;
 clear:left;
}

.previmg:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lightbox_container">
  <div class="lightboxsm" id="img1">
    <img src="http://2017.sunkissed-villas.com/images/1.png" alt="1"/>
  </div>
        
  <div class="lightboxsm" id="img2">
    <img src="http://2017.sunkissed-villas.com/images/2.png" alt="2"/>
  </div>
            
  <div class="lightboxsm" id="img3">
    <img src="http://2017.sunkissed-villas.com/images/3.png"/>
  </div>            
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to add the same to previmg selector also.

Comment: THANK YOU so much!!!  This worked great.  I still need to fix the hide and show when there isn't another option, but this is exactly what I needed.  I also added the previous option.  THANK YOU!  :)

Comment: Glad it worked, would you like me to edit the answer to fix the hide and show as well?

Comment: If you want to, that would be great.  I tried a few things and failed.  Just not familiar with the parent/child handling.  New to JQuery and javascript.

Comment: Just did that as well, if it works and your question has been answered go ahead and mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help.